# Runscope complex initial variable

Tags: javascript, variables, md5, runscope

How can I initialize complex initial variable for my test. Something like:

```
variables.set("token", md5("something" + md5("something" + somevalue + "some other value") + "some value one more time" + someVal));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dmytro, almost exactly the way that you have described. Runscope provides the [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) library, and you would do it this way:

```
var someValue = "woot";
variables.set("token", CryptoJS.MD5("something" + 
  CryptoJS.MD5("foo1" + someValue + "someOtherValue").toString() +
  "foo2" + someValue).toString());
```

The full Runscope scripts documentation is [here](https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/scripts).

Comment: Now I have something like this in the `token` var `{u'sigBytes': 16, u'words': [528991511, -2135870435, -962585958, 1753796243]}`

Comment: I have added `.toString()` to the `MD5()` method result and it works now.